# Following the chrome extension tutorial got "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing )" after running code given in the tutorial

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have been following this tutorial to make [extensions on Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted) but got stuck at a step where I had to write a JS file and compile it. The code is already provided in the tutorial.

```js
let changeColor = document.getElementById('changeColor');

  chrome.storage.sync.get('color', function(data) {
    changeColor.style.backgroundColor = data.color;
    changeColor.setAttribute('value', data.color);
  });
```

But when I tried to reload the extension it gave the following error:

[image: JS Error]

So I looked up the [chrome.storage API](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/storage#type-StorageArea) documentation which had a similar syntax:

```js
chrome.storage.sync.get(['key'], function(result) {
         console.log('Value currently is ' + result.key);
       });
```

I changed the code a little to debug it:

```js
chrome.storage.sync.get(['color'], function(data) {
          console.log('Value currently is ' + data.color);
        });
```

and I get the same error:

[image]

Could someone explain what I am missing?

Comment: Remove the pictures and show the actual code as text.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I reloaded the program after 5 days and it is now somehow working, don't know how this worked.